# Check whether all buttons are same colour, then display text Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have this code here:

```
function toggle(i,j) {
  b=document.getElementById("but_" + i + j)
  t = b.innerHTML
  if (t=="X") {b.innerHTML = "O";
               b.setAttribute( "style", "color:red; background-color:yellow" )
              }
  if (t=="O") {b.innerHTML = "X";
               b.setAttribute( "style", "color:white; background-color:black" )
              }
}

function press(i, j) {
toggle(i, j);

if (i > 0) {
toggle(i-1, j);
}
if (i < 4) {
toggle(i+1, j);
}
if (j > 0) {
toggle(i, j-1);
}
if (j < 4) {
toggle(i, j+1);
}
}



function generateGrid() {
    var d = document.getElementById("button-grid");
    var table = document.createElement("table");
    d.appendChild(table);
    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            var row = document.createElement("tr");
            for (var j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
                    var cell = document.createElement("td");
                    cell.innerHTML = "<button type=button id=but_" + i + j +
                                     " onclick=\"press(" +i + ',' +j + ")\"" + 
                                     " style=\"color:red; background-color:yellow\"" +
                                     ">O</button>" ;
                    row.appendChild(cell);
            }
            table.appendChild(row);
    }
    toggle(2,2)
}

window.onload = function() {
    generateGrid();
};
```

What I want to do is display some text using html saying for example "All the boxes are black" when all the boxes have been turned black. When not all the boxes are black, I want no text to display at all.

If you need any more information please let me know, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the code below to find the color of an element.

```
$("#test").css('color')
```

The code above would give you the color of something with an id of "test". You can change the id to what you would need, and just create a for loop looping through your grid.

```js
var color = $('.but_00').css('background-color');
var colorsAreEqual = true;

for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
    if ($('.but_' + i + j).css('background-color') != color) {
      colorsAreEqual = false;
    }
  }
}
if (colorsAreEqual) {
  //The boxes are all the same color
  console.log("The colors are all " + color);
} else {
  //The boxes are not all the same color, so it displays nothing. 
  console.log("The colors are not the same");
}
```

```css
#button {
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="but_00" id="button">1</button>
<button class="but_01" id="button">1</button>
<button class="but_02" id="button">1</button>
<button class="but_03" id="button">1</button>
<button class="but_04" id="button">1</button>
<button class="but_10" id="button">1</button>
<button class="but_11" id="button">1</button>
<button class="but_12" id="button">1</button>
<button class="but_13" id="button">1</button>
<button class="but_14" id="button">1</button>
<button class="but_20" id="button">1</button>
<button class="but_21" id="button">1</button>
<button class="but_22" id="button">1</button>
<button class="but_23" id="button">1</button>
<button class="but_24" id="button">1</button>
<button class="but_30" id="button">1</button>
<button class="but_31" id="button">1</button>
<button class="but_32" id="button">1</button>
<button class="but_33" id="button">1</button>
<button class="but_34" id="button">1</button>
<button class="but_40" id="button">1</button>
<button class="but_41" id="button">1</button>
<button class="but_42" id="button">1</button>
<button class="but_43" id="button">1</button>
<button class="but_44" id="button">1</button>
```

Comment: how would I be able to implement this with my code?

Comment: There I edited the code above to make it like yours. I don't know how you want to implement this into your code, but it would be something like above.

Comment: does this not create 25 new buttons? I was hoping to be able to do this purely in javascript, which would hide/unhide a <h3>All the boxes are black</h3> depending on whether the 5x5 grid I already have is all black or not. Thanks

Comment: Ignore the html code and the 25 I had - I didn't copy your code, so I had to make my own buttons. You would've already created those buttons. I can't implement this in your code exactly, because I don't know what it's doing, but based off your description of the problem, the code is above. You'll have to read the code and implement it yourself.